Problem installing rgdal as I need to use the associated readOGR() function
Using R version 4.3.2, I have used the getData() function from the raster package to read a dataset to make a "KUD plot" in ggplot2.
However, I have a polygon shapefile (.shp) with geometry that I want to read with readOGR() but I cannot install rgdal:
install.packages("rgdal")


Warning in install.packages :
package ‘rgdal’ is not available for this version of R
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

I tried to install rgdal with an older version of R but it doesn't work.
My problem is that need to add a coastline using geom_polygon(). I have an existing SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, but it is not detailed enough. This is what I tried:
ggplot() +
  coord_sf(crs = 32632)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver95), color= NA, fill="#3B9AB2", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver90), color= NA, fill="#48A0B6", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver85), color= NA, fill="#56A6BA", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver80), color= NA, fill="#63ADBE", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver75), color= NA, fill="#71B3C2", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver70), color= NA, fill="#84B9B3", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver65), color= NA, fill="#9EBE91", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver60), color= NA, fill="#B7C26E", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver55), color= NA, fill="#D1C74C", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver50), color= NA, fill="#EBCC2A", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver45), color= NA, fill="#E8C520", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver40), color= NA, fill="#E6BF17", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver35), color= NA, fill="#E4B80E", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver30), color= NA, fill="#E2B204", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver25), color= NA, fill="#E29E00", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver20), color= NA, fill="#E67D00", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver15), color= NA, fill="#EA5C00", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver10), color= NA, fill="#EE3B00", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(ver05), color= NA, fill="#F21A00", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(mcp), color= "black", fill=NA, alpha=0.5)+
 geom_point(data = Stations, aes(x=station_longitude, y = station_latitude),
            shape=21, color="red", size = 2) +
  geom_point(data = COA, aes(x=Longitude.coa, y = Latitude.coa), shape=3, color="black", size = 1) + ### points COAs
  ylab("Latitude") +
  xlab("Longitude")+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(9.43, 9.55195), ylim = c(42.551657, 42.68), expand = FALSE)+   
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_polygon(data = Corsica , aes(x=long, y=lat))+

  ggtitle("KUD blue crab")+ theme_bw()

this is what I got:

Here's the plot without the coastline to show why I need rgdal to read a more detailed coastline e.g. some data get obscured:


I haven't done geospatial in a while. rgdal has been archived since : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html. I think that you could rely on sf package , with sf::st_read(). You seems to already have sf since you used  st_as_sf.

Thanks for your response, i tried to use sf::st_read() like this :
Corsica <- sf::st_read(dsn = "Fonds-cartes/EEA_Coastline_Polygon_Shape", layer = "EEA_Coastline_20170228")
But i have this as response, and don't know how to fix it...
Error in st_transform.sfc(X[[i]], ...) :    cannot transform sfc object with missing crs

what was your call exactly? st_read("myshapefile.shp")  usually works for my type of polygons.  I think that you can specify the crs later.

As you observed, your data were not detailed enough so some KUD data were obscured. Also, I strongly recommend using geom_sf() when plotting spatial data as the use of other geom options can lead to issues.
As mentioned in the comments, rgdal was deprecated October 2023. This repex uses the sf package, which the relevant rgdal functions have migrated to. Note that if rgdal has previously been installed, it may cause problems so you may need to remove all traces of it from your library directory before installing sf. This includes the versions of GDAL, GEOS, and PROJ that rgdal binds to.
I managed to source the dataset you are using for your plot from this link, and have provided a workflow to achieve what you want. It involves creating a LINESTRING and POLYGON version of the data and then cropping both to your area of interest You will need to unzip the download into your work directory first, and update your packages if necessary.
If you want to use xlim/ylim values inside coord_sf(), you will need to convert your current WGS84:EPSG4326 xlim/ylim values to their equivalent EPSG:32632 values. I got around this by cropping the coastline data to your original xlim/ylim values prior to plotting. However, if your other data extend beyond those xlim/ylim values, you'll need to edit the code accordingly.
library(dplyr) # 1.1.4
library(sf) # 1.0.15
library(ggplot2) # 3.5.0

# Data downloaded from https://sdi.eea.europa.eu/datashare/s/esBJK983EZpAZJg/download
# and unzipped to getwd()
Corsica_line <- st_read("EEA_Coastline_20170228.shp") %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  st_crop(xmin = 9.43, ymin = 42.551657, xmax = 9.55195, ymax = 42.68) %>%
  st_transform(32632)

Corsica_poly <- st_read("EEA_Coastline_20170228.shp") %>%
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  st_crop(xmin = 9.43, ymin = 42.551657, xmax = 9.55195, ymax = 42.68) %>%
  st_transform(32632)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = Corsica_poly,
          fill = "grey70",
          colour = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = Corsica_line,
          colour = "grey30") +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
  # coord_sf(xlim = c(9.43, 9.55195),
  #          ylim = c(42.551657, 42.68),
  #          expand = FALSE) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

Result:

